# Why does E.T. move towards the Yoda-like kid while calling "Home Home"?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, star-wars, et-the-extra-terrestrial, steven-spielberg

In the 1982 classic E.T., when Elliot and Mike take E.T. out on Halloween, E.T. sees people dressed up in bizarre costumes, but when a kid dressed up like Yoda walks aside, E.T is seen rushing towards him saying "Home Home".
Now Yoda is a fictional character for people on earth. How come E.T. recognizes him and relates to him?
Did Steven Spielberg want to suggest by this scene that Yoda maybe actually exists?
What's the meaning behind this scene?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's just a gag/joke or just a promise between Spielberg  and Lucas (who knew each other from film school) started from E.T. and ended on Star Wars Episode I: The Phantom Menace.

> Grebleips' species are a cameo appearance of the famous aliens of
> Steven Spielberg's 1982 film E.T. the Extra-Terrestrial. These
> creatures were inserted in the movie to make good on a promise—after
> Steven Spielberg included a Yoda cameo and Star Wars toys in E.T.,
> George Lucas promised to include an E.T. cameo in the next Star Wars
> film he made—The Phantom Menace. While this is primarily an easter
> egg, and E.T. is probably not meant to be taken as part of Star Wars
> canon, some Star Wars references in E.T. can be reinterpreted in light
> of the E.T. references in Star Wars.(source:[starwars.fandom.com](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Asogian/Legends))

So it's a promise between Spielberg and Lucas that both allow to use each others character in their films like gag.

Their is a good link to read on this [Does Earth Exist In The Star Wars Universe?](https://www.liveabout.com/does-earth-exist-star-wars-universe-2958000)

Even a similar question present on Scifi as [Are E.T. and Star Wars in the same universe?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6555/are-e-t-and-star-wars-in-the-same-universe) with a good analytic answer.

Comment: @Oliver_C why you deleted your own answer? I think you should keep it too. Both answer are similar but you used diffrent links and wording.

Answer (score 4):

As [**Wookieepedia**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Asogian/Legends) explains:

> ***Grebleips***' [*Spielberg* spelled backwards] species are a cameo appearance of the famous aliens of Steven Spielberg's 1982 film [***E.T. the Extra-Terrestrial***](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083866/).

> [image: E.T.]

> **These creatures were inserted in the movie [***Star Wars Episode I: The Phantom Menace***](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120915/) to make good on a promise—after Steven Spielberg included a *Yoda* cameo and *Star Wars toys* in *E.T.*,**

> [image: Yoda in E.T.]

> **George Lucas promised to include an *E.T.* cameo in the next *Star Wars* film he made —*The Phantom Menace*.**

> While this **is primarily an easter egg,** and E.T. is probably not meant to be taken as part of Star Wars canon, some Star Wars references in E.T. can be reinterpreted in light of the E.T. references in Star Wars.