# Does George Lucas mention Earth in "Star Wars"?

Tags: star-wars

In the Star Wars movies by George Lucas, is anything ever mentioned about Earth and the Milky Way Galaxy?

Comment: The very first line in the film's iconic crawl is "A long time ago in a galaxy far, far away... " why would the Earth be mentioned?

Comment: A long, long time ago in a galaxy **far, far away...**

Comment: Maybe its saying Farfar away but im asking did he mentioned anything about earth & milky way in a movie inside? like some space ship came to our galexy may be crash in to Earth some thing ship that kind of things

Comment: by the way Guys Gorge Lucas Saying When starting a Star wars Movie "A long time ago in a galaxy far, far away..." where is it mentioned its from Earth or Milky way Galaxy? he should start like  this "A long time ago in a galaxy far, far away from Earth & Milky way Galaxy...

Comment: Of course, one might ask oneself, "Far Far away" from *WHERE*?

Comment: Out of scope for the movies stackexchange, but there are (non-canon) comic crossovers: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Into_the_Great_Unknown

Comment: The opening titles are obviously addressing the audience (on Earth). It would make zero sense that it would be in relation to a third, unknown galaxy that's never mentioned in the films.

Comment: What if earth just does not exist yet? After all, it is a long time ago. For all we know, earth ends up getting created from the remains of obliterated death star victims. Jk of course. The death star isn't that powerful.

Comment: In the novelization of the first movie, Obi-Wan mentioned a duck at some point, causing Luke to ask "what's a duck".

Comment: I found this: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_references_to_Earth_in_Star_Wars

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Famously from the opening credits of Star Wars it is set...

[image: A long time ago in a galaxy far, far away....]

Essentially this is an equivalent to the fairy tale 'once upon a time' opening.  It tells us that it's not really important where or when the story is set.

There are however exceptionally tenuous movie links to the Earth - in that you see creatures like [E.T.](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083866/) in the Republic council meetings:

[image: E.T. like creatures in the council meetings]

However this is barely more than an 'easter egg' than a true linking to Earth in the Star Wars universe. So I would have to conclude that the answer is 'no'.

Comment: Related question for E.T. ,  [Why E.T. moves towards Yoda like kid calling “Home Home”?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/10671/why-e-t-moves-towards-yoda-like-kid-calling-home-home)

Comment: Ironically, that intro kinda *is* an implicit mention of Earth and our own reality. ;) ["A long, long time ago in a galaxy far, far away..." from *us*.]

Comment: @Walt Well, the intro crawl doesn't exist in-universe. It's part of our extra-diegetic narrative.

Answer (score 24):

Yes, although in all fairness more as a gag than as a serious canon fact. Then again, Jar-Jar Binks is a serious canon fact, so who am I to judge canon? :)

I have discussed the links in detail in [my answer to "**Are E.T. and Star Wars in the same universe?**" SFF Q&A](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6555/are-e-t-and-star-wars-in-the-same-universe/6558#6558).

I shall now shamelessly borrow from that answer the way J.J. Abrams borrowed from Episode IV :)

**TL;DR: Yes.**

- As a gag/easter egg/cross-merchandizing/friendly jest/whatever, Spielberg and Lucas have placed enough canon information in their universes to imply that E.T. really is an alien from a species in a Star Wars Galaxy.
- E.T.'s species were officially called [The Children of the Green Planet](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Children_of_the_Green_Planet), their planet was called [Brodo Asogi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Brodo_Asogi).
- In addition, as documented in my [SFF answer to "**Are Star Wars and Indiana Jones the same Universe?**"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/12182/976), there is a second mention: somehow, Indiana Jones's The Ark of the Covenant is strongly implied to originate fron... Han Solo's Episode VII cargo ship "Erevana":

  [image]

  [image]

Comment: It's probably worth noting that it would have been on the Millennium Falcon *first* and *then* end up on Earth.

Comment: @Mystagogue: Yes, people forget that Star Wars is ancient history rather than futuristic

Comment: @sleb good catch! Fixed

Comment: I don't think the Ark connection works as anything more than an Easter egg/numerical coincidence, since the Ark isn't found in a numbered crate. That's only what it is placed in at the very end of the movie.

Comment: Theres a decent Star Wars comic titled "Into the Great Uknown" that has Han and Chewie end up on Earth and meet Indy.  Although this comic is given as non-canon so it doesn't count, it's basically another neat easter egg that goes to show more of the connection between the two series.

Answer (score 6):

Another "easter egg" type instance of things *related* to earth being included in the movie is the person in the potential Gemini/Mercury spacesuit in one scene.

Thread discussing it here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80002/what-evidence-is-there-that-proves-disproves-there-was-a-gemini-earth-astronaut

[image]

But of course since this is a galaxy far away and a long long time ago this is more of a costume budget issue than an in-universe reference to Earth.

Answer (score 5):

While the Battlestar Gallactica series did make reference to Earth that they didn't know if it existed or not, in Star Wars, never is Earth mentioned at all.  That is different than saying that in the opening text it says "A long time ago, in a Galaxy far far away."  One might say that at some other point earth is mentioned, but no, it is never mentioned.

Curiously, by saying "A long time ago, in a Galaxy far, far away..." it does imply an audience that is being addressed.  So, it is told to an audience on Earth and the events happened a long time ago from our point of view and a Galaxy far from us.  Still, in no way does the movie ever make reference to Earth at all.

Comment: Well, yeah... You never know where in the universe the narrator is and to which audience he's narrating to and to which far far away galaxy he's referring to.

Answer (score 2):

Several characters in Episode I refer to humans - C3PO ("human-cyborg relations"), Anakin ("I'm the only human who can do it"), and a pod race announcer ("that little human being is out of his mind").  This is not a direct mention of Earth but Earth may well be an origin of humans.

Comment: Since Star Wars takes place "a long time ago", wouldn't that make it more likely that humans came from elsewhere in the universe, and later settled Earth?

Comment: Or maybe the Star Wars humans are descended from the ancient humans that Stargate's Goa'uld stole from Earth and populated other galaxies with as slave labor. Some of those humans fought independence and spread out, so who is to say some didn't populate the Star Wars galaxy at some point. Just saying... :-)

Comment: And they're talking English. But ... wait ... no they're not! Everything's translated for us, including the word "human". I wouldn't take it literally. (BSG excellently lampshaded exactly this by taking what the characters called "human" and "Earth" and turning them on their head.)

Comment: What makes you think humans necessarily have to originate from Earth? What else should they call these guys, Migorians? Of course they're humans.

Comment: From Farscape (not mentioned yet), we know humans are not from Earth, so humans in Star Wars cannot be from Earth either. But if we now include Jupiter Ascending too, then it will be a even more complex. And what to think of Interstellar, which puts humans on Earth before they were on Earth. Now, go ahead, and rewrite human history including these and more, and see the complexity you can get by linking all humans in movies and series together. I would be very interested in timelines derived from this. BTW, don't forget Dune and Stargate.

Comment: @PeterHofman The Eidelons took ancient humans from Earth to make the Peacekeepers from, of course humans are from Earth in Farscape.

Answer (score 1):

In the movies, there was no direct mention of earth. So the answer to your movie-related question is "No".

But in the expanded universe, there were mentioned, that the Rakatan Empire found humans on some planet and spread them around the whole universe, but it was not the earth. So in the movies, there is no direct answer where do humans come from, but in the extended universe, it is clearly stated, that humans are not from earth.

Answer (score 0):

### Implicitly, yes.

> A long time ago, in a galaxy far, far away...

This pins the events of Star Wars as occurring "a long time" before 1977 and in the same universe as Earth, albeit in another galaxy that is "far, far away." A long time and far away are both subjective measures, but we can at least infer that the events are occurring in a different galaxy than the Milky Way. This could well be the nearest galaxy to us: the Andromeda Galaxy, which is about 2.5 million light years away. Certainly that is far, far away... though by galactic standards, it's our next door neighbor. The farthest known galaxy is 13 *billion* light years away, which by comparison makes 2.5 million light years not so far.

In any event, the very first words on the screen reference the events of the film in relation to Earth and the year 1977.